# Rhythmbox is missing last.fm like button

Tags: rhythmbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rhythmbox is missing last.fm and libre.fm like button in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156350/rhythmbox-is-missing-last-fm-and-libre-fm-like-button-in-12-04)

So, Rhythmbox used to have buttons for "loving song" and "banning song" for the last.fm stream. This is important, because clicking the love song button make the song appear more on the stream.

In Precise, I couldn't find it. Was it removed or is it just missing?

Comment: This is a bug so you should report a bug against Rhythmbox upstream.

Comment: I filled the bug report but there was no answer =/
I think it is easier to just switch music players..

Comment: @gustavokrm I filed a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122345/rhythmbox-is-missing-last-fm-like-button), there is a third party plugin for rhythmbox  that fixes that bug.