# Rhythmbox is missing last.fm and libre.fm like button in 12.04

Tags: rhythmbox

I've just updated and those buttons are gone. Any ideas how I can have these buttons back?

There is a duplicated question over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122345/rhythmbox-is-missing-last-fm-like-button) but it was closed as off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### lastfm like buttons

The version in 12.04 has a plugin to LastFM built in - however as you have found, no longer has the like buttons.

Fortunately, a third-party developer has stepped in to provide this;

called *lastfm-extension* the plugin:

The [homepage](https://github.com/asermax/lastfm_extension) has the installation instructions.

[image]

As per my answer:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins/147943#147943)

I've packaged this together with other optional plugins in my PPA.